# YOLO v4 environment building

Tags: yolo

I follow the steps with video to build the yolo v4 environment.
P.S. video is Chinese.
[video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVf16gIhnek&t=1898s)

But when I want to test the result, there is a error I dont know how to solve.

the error:

```
CUDA-version: 11050 (11050), cuDNN: 8.3.0, GPU count: 1
OpenCV version: 4.1.0
0 : compute_capability = 610, cudnn_half = 0, GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX250
net.optimized_memory = 0
mini_batch = 1, batch = 8, time_steps = 1, train = 0
layer filters size/strd(dil) input output
0 Create CUDA-stream - 0
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126
Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path!
```

Plz help me, thanks

[Error image][2]

Comment: 早上好! Explain a little bit what you're struggling with. Post the errors you get.

Comment: I watched the video you linked to. Good but lacks some steps (my Chinese is limited so I might have misunderstood things). Look at this video https://youtu.be/saDipJR14Lc

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes 你好! I only encounterd one proplem which is in the Error image link. The main problem is "Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126" when I test.

Comment: For the future. Do not post images of data or errors. Post them as formatted text. :-)

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Ok, thanks. It's my first time to ask the question here, so I  dont know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following thing. Download the cuda zip file and locate it. Copy all these files:

```
    cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
    cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
    cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
    cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
    cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
    cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
```

And paste  them in your nvidia gpu computing toolkit>cuda>bin

Alternatively, if you've already have these files move them to the folder. You might encounter new errors of the same type for other dll fes. Do the same with those.

I had the same issue and solved it that way.

Comment: I've done this way, but still happened same error "Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126".

Comment: It isn't so that you have multiple versions of Cuda, right? Are you running tensorflow? If so, which version?

Comment: And you've pasted in the right place  "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin"?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, my yesterday download was the latest CUDA 11.5 and cuDNN 8.3.  Both cant support my tensorflow 2.6.0, so i think yolov4 is too. Then I change to CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1, then enviroment building success. i sincerely grateful to u

Comment: In case if it helps anyone, I am using CUDA 11.3 so i added the above files in the following location : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin and then updated the system path to point to it. That resolved the problem for me. These files do not come with the 11.3 package so you can download cuDNN 8.2.4 (this works for me) and copy the files to CUDA11.3, no need of removing this CUDA version and installing an older one.